# Can't send email from google group account using Email::MIME in Perl / CC'd don't receive email

Tags: perl, email, mime

I want to send an email notification from a google group account for whenever bad content is found in my perl script that reads and decodes json data.

Here's what I'm working  with:

```
  my $email = Email::MIME->create(
    header_str => [
      From           => 'test@googlegroup.com',
      To             => 'me@gmail.com',
      Cc             => ('other1@gmail.com', 'other2@gmail.com', 'other3@gmail.com'),
      Subject        => 'YOrg Refresh Failed: Bad File',
      'Content-Type' => 'text/html',
    ],
    body => "<p>All,</p><p>An error occurred while processing the data from the latest refresh.</p><p>Please look into this as soon as possible.</p>"
  );
  sendmail($email);
  die $response->status_line;
```

I tested this first by using my personal email address as the sender (From), and the email sent out as expected. But when I went with using the group account address ('test@googlegroup.com'), the email didn't send out. It's a valid group account, too. So I'm not sure why the email wouldn't send from that account.

Additionally, in the test instance where I sent from my personal email address, only the 'other1@gmail.com' alias received the email, and none of the other cc'd addresses got it.

Answer (score 3):

The latter half of your problem is that you're trying to assign a list to a hash value instead of a reference to an anonymous array.  This:

```
Cc => ('other1@gmail.com', 'other2@gmail.com', 'other3@gmail.com'),
```

should be:

```
Cc => ['other1@gmail.com', 'other2@gmail.com', 'other3@gmail.com'],
```

Since you're giving it a list, Perl is parsing your statement like this:

```
header_str => [
  From               => 'test@googlegroup.com',
  To                 => 'me@gmail.com',
  Cc                 => 'other1@gmail.com',
  'other2@gmail.com' => 'other3@gmail.com',
  Subject            => 'YOrg Refresh Failed: Bad File',
  'Content-Type'     => 'text/html',
],
```